# Fading Colours in Blender Render

Tags: objects

I'm trying to fade one colour into another colour in blender render without using cycles render. Someone please tell me there's a way.

Comment: ...and what you tried until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the Diffuse color parameter :

Put your mouse over the color selector, press I to insert a key. The color selector should be highlighted in yellow to show that a key is present.

Move a few frames forward, change the color, then insert a new key.

(You can do the same with almost every parameter)

Comment: Im sorry I worded that wrong. Say I have a plane and one side is black and the other side is green. I want the 2 colours to fade into each other with no animation. I hope you understand cause this is driving me nuts lol

Comment: I didn't use blender render for a while, but you can do that with a Blend texture and a Green/Black color ramp.

Comment: where do I find blender texture? node editor?

Comment: In the Properties editor, "checker" icon, close to material icon. Add a new texture, in "type" select Blend. In "Color" tick "Ramp", then edit the ramp to choose your colors.

Comment: Thanks to you I got it the way I want it to look! I really appreciate your help.